# Bounding Box & Segmentation Mask of a Blender Particle System

Tags: python, blender, bpy

I m trying to simulate multiple falling objects with a particle system in blender.

To train certain CNN's I require the segmentation mask of single elements that are visible in the scene. Up to now I m only able to perform part of the exporting mask task. Such as exporting a mask by composition nodes or using python to extract some properties.

What I tried so far is :

- Exporting the mask via particle indices (See Images). The colors of the objects in the segmentation image randomly vary. Since they will overlap at some point, this solution is not really applicable. The edges of the segmentation image is also quite fuzzy, mainly to the setting: Film -> Pixel Filter -> Width property (If set to 0, the rendered image is
  also affected).

[image: Shading Nodes]
[image: Composition Nodes]

- Another possibility that I see is exporting the mask by python. Therefore I created a script which (up to now) exports the centerpoints of the particles in the image. However I could probably loop over the visible particles and disable one by one and always save the image, but this will use a tremendous amount of memory and time.

```
    import bpy
    from bpy_extras.object_utils import world_to_camera_view
    
    context = bpy.context
    dg = context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
    ob = context.object.evaluated_get(dg)
    
    ps = ob.particle_systems.active
    
    scene = bpy.context.scene
    cam = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
    
    render = scene.render
    res_x = render.resolution_x
    res_y = render.resolution_y
    
    for frame in range(30,35):
        scene.frame_set(frame)
        bpy.ops.render.render(write_still = True)
        
        print("res_x:{},res_y:{}".format(res_x, res_y))
        for particle in ps.particles:
            if particle.is_visible:
                print(particle.location)
                coords_2d = world_to_camera_view(scene, cam, particle.location)
                x = coords_2d[0]
                y = coords_2d[1]
                dist_to_cam = coords_2d[2]
                rnd = lambda i: round(i)
                print("x:{},y:{}".format(rnd(res_x*x),res_y- rnd(res_y*y)))
```

If someone could show me a more reliable clean method to export the masks of all the visible single particle objects, also considering overlapping, in blender I would highly appreciate it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Blenderproc!
You can generate synthetic datasets from blender 3D models

https://github.com/DLR-RM/BlenderProc

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to write an image with just the mask of the particle.

This [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272410/python-how-to-change-compositors-file-output-nodes-image-name-without-frame-n) helped a lot, since it was accessing the File_Output node.

In the Composition Tab of Blender, I used the ID Mask node to display just one Masked object - selected by their id.
[image]

The ID Mask node and the file Output node can be accessed the following way :

```
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].node_tree.nodes["File Output"].file_slots[3].path = "Particle_Mask_{}_#####".format(particle_id)
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].node_tree.nodes["ID Mask"].index = particle_id
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=False)
```

The final step now only requires a rendering with `write_still=False`. Since this code is in the for loop of all particles, it will write only the visible one.